# (Android) D/OkHttp: 400 Bad Request

Tags: android, api, rx-java

```
@Headers("Authorization: " + BuildConfig.CLIENT_ID + " " + BuildConfig.CLIENT_SECRET)
@GET("get/list")
Observable<List<Post>> getList();
```

Inside the get folder u can find such .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
AuthName "Staff Only:3"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile .../api/get/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Get/list returns json array of posts. There r no 400 code in that php code. I also sure in my json response, its correct(confirmed by jsonschema2pojo.org)
The Header(codeblock 1) is really authorize me.

And...

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://*********/api/get/list http/1.1
D/OkHttp: Authorization: r*******m *******6
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
...
D/OkHttp: <-- 400 Bad Request http://*********/api/get/list (18711ms)
D/OkHttp: Date: Sun, 19 Mar 2017 20:13:11 GMT
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 177
D/OkHttp: Connection: close
D/OkHttp: Server: -nginx
D/OkHttp: CF-RAY: -
D/OkHttp: <html>
D/OkHttp: <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
D/OkHttp: <body bgcolor="white">
D/OkHttp: <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
D/OkHttp: <hr><center>cloudflare-nginx</center>
D/OkHttp: </body>
D/OkHttp: </html>
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (177-byte body)
```

Wth? Why? Pls tell me whats the problem? Could u help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP file returns `Content-Type: text/html` instead of `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8`, thats why you get 400. Set the header on your PHP file.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
```

From [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Comment: I did that 10 hours ago (i asked about this on [russian stackoverflow 2days ago](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641698/android-d-okhttp-400-bad-request). My PHP starts with `<?php header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");`
Still not working